# Buscar elementos com uma determinada distância de tempo (informando apenas o tempo)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Detalhe sqlserver(2008)
Boa noite, estou com seguinte problema. Tentei procurar o dia todo e não encontrei nada.
-Preciso buscar elementos em uma mesma tabela que tenham a mesma data(dia, hora ...) e uma distancia de tempo de no máximo 40 segundos de um para o outro.

Exemplo:

```
ID --- data
1      09-11-2018 19:01:10
2      09-11-2018 19:01:30
3      09-11-2018 19:01:40
----------------------------------------
4      09-11-2018 19:02:00  <--exemplo de dado que nao deveria entrar
```

OBS: Quero que a query busque os dados, com essa distancia de tempo de acordo com a tabela ***sem informar dado algum a não ser os segundos.***

Tentei da seguinte forma abaixo: 
mas sem sucesso, no resultado alguns dados se repetem e outros não coincidem com o esperado.

```
select *
from TABELA t join
     TABELA tnext
     on 
     datepart(DAY,  t.Data) = datepart(DAY, tnext.Data) and 
     datepart(HOUR,  t.Data) = datepart(HOUR, tnext.Data) and
     datepart(minute,  t.Data) = datepart(minute, tnext.Data) and
     datediff(second,  t.Data, tnext.Data) < 40
```

Comment: `LAG()` + `DATEDIFF(Second,..)`

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a função `LAG ()` se estiver trabalhando na versão 2012+ ao lado da função `DATEDIFF()`

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  ID INT,
  Data DATETIME
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, '09-11-2018 19:01:10'),
(2, '09-11-2018 19:01:30'),
(3, '09-11-2018 19:01:40'),
(4, '09-11-2018 19:02:20'); --Você tem dados errados aqui não é 40 segundos

WITH C AS
(
SELECT ID,
       Data,
       CASE WHEN LAG(Data, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ID) = '01/01/1900 00:00:00' THEN
        NULL
        ELSE
        LAG(Data, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
       END PrevDate
FROM T
)
SELECT * 
FROM C
WHERE DATEDIFF(Second, PrevDate, Data) = 40;
```

**Retorna:**

```
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
| ID |        Data         |      PrevDate       |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
|  4 | 11/09/2018 19:02:20 | 11/09/2018 19:01:40 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Para cada linha da tabela pode existir um subconjunto de linhas que estejam no intervalo de 40 segundos. Uma mesma linha pode participar de mais de um subconjunto.

```
-- código #1
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Data, T2.Data
  from tabela as T1
       inner join tabela as T2 on T2.Data > T1.Data
                                  and T2.Data < dateadd (second, +40, T1.Data)
  order by T1.ID, T2.Data;
```

No resultado do código #1 todas as linhas com mesmo valor de ID formam um subconjunto.

Outra solução:

```
-- código #2
SELECT T1.ID, T1.Data, T2.Data
  from tabela as T1
       cross join tabela as T2
  where T2.Data > T1.Data
        and T2.Data < dateadd (second, +40, T1.Data)
  order by T1.ID, T2.Data;
```

Comment: Deu certo para mim a primeira opção, muito obrigado amigo. Deus abençoe